# Matlab fsolve optimization terminated

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I used fsolve to solve a function but the result shows

Optimization terminated: norm of relative change in X is less
 than max(options.TolX^2,eps) and  sum-of-squares of function 
 values is less than sqrt(options.TolFun).

A =
    0.3490

Anybody knows how to solve this? Thanks!

My code is as below

```
clear

M=10000;
x0=0.35;
Z=randn(M,1);
A=fsolve(@(x)function_1_5_3(x,Z),x0)


function f=function_1_5_3(x,Z)

r0=.02;%interest rate
sigma=.15;%vatality rate of risky asset
mu0=.06;%drift rate of risky asset
gamma=5;%risk aversion rate
M=10000;%number of trajectories
N=55;%time period
T=55;%total time period
R=40;%time of retirement
dt=T/N;%each time period
t=1:dt:T;
omega=x;
Rf=exp(r0);%riskless reture
mat=rand(M,N);

Rs=exp(mu0+sigma*Z);%risky market return
a=20*mat(:,N-2);
a_1=20*mat(:,N-1);

W=((a.*(Rf+omega*(Rs-Rf))-a_1).^(-gamma)).*(Rs-Rf);%regard as function 4

f=mean(W);
```

Comment: you need a pure function for fsolve.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem at all?

When performing an optimization (i.e. finding the value A so that function_1_5_3 becomes very small), you need to define what you consider a good solution. There's no point in waiting for days while parameters are modified by `eps` to eke out that one little bit of improvement in the solution.

There are several common heuristics to identify a "good enough" solution, for example if the x-values don't change a lot anymore, or if the function value doesn't change a lot anymore. Using the `options` argument to `fsolve`, which allows you to set values using `optimset`, you can select the tolerance in the unknowns (`options.TolX`), as well as the tolerance in the function value (`options.TolFun`), i.e. the amounts of change that are "small enough" to consider that the function has converged.

In your case, both the tolerance on the function values and the tolerance on the x-values is satisfied for the optimization. It is a bit surprising that both should happen at the same time. If the result is not optimal, you should either check whether you should modify the tolerances, whether you have made a mistake in the formula, or whether you e.g. meant `fminsearch` when you were writing `fsolve`.